# Dont know how to display passive devices in network

Tags: networking

I have a question about devices in standby-mode on my Wi-Fi network.
My configuration consists of a Fritzbox3490 and a Raspberry-PI3.
In my Fritzbox connection menu (fritz.box) i can see passive devices (overall 14) like my smartphone in stand-by, my PI on the other hand is not able to show me passive devices (only 10).
I tried many programs like ARP-Scan, netdiscover..., but these programs only showed me the active devices. I also tried the fritzconnection api, but it did not work for me. I must admit that I am new in networking. Is there a way to get the passive devices on the console or in a python script, which are connected the fritzbox?

Comment: Do you mean you tried "fritzwlan.py"? It looks like it's *supposed* to do what you want.  "It did not work" is not very specific :-), although I personally might not be able to help even if I saw the details.

Comment: Not sure about your Fritzbox, but my Fritzbox remembers devices that have connected to it in the past, and also shows these devices in the UI. Could that be what you are seeing? If a device is not using WLAN, there is **no** way to identify it (other than remembering it from a time where it *was* using WLAN).

Comment: When i run python fritzwlan.py i get the error: "fritzconnection.ActionError: Unknown Action: GetTotalAssociation". The Problem is, that in the service WANIPConnection, there is no action; GetTotalAssociation

Comment: If i try another action whitch is in the listed actions like GetExternalIPAdress, i get other errors like Unknown Action: GetGerericAssociateddeviceInfo. The Problem is, that this package was last updated Jul 2017

Comment: The router does have extra information that other network devices don't.  Specifically the DHCP server will store the MAC address and previous IP of recently connected devices.  This can be long lived, many routers lease IPs for between 1 day and 1 week.  On some routers this is shared with the router's own ARP table meaning that the router only ever has to ARP for devices which do not use a DHCP client to configure their network.

Comment: I don't have a Fritzbox to test this on but [`fritzhosts.py`](https://pypi.org/project/fritzconnection/) looks like the python module you need.  If you have problems making this work then you might need to ask a more programmer related question on it (eg on stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Fritzhosts.py works for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I dunno.

We had a very similar-sounding problem trying to `ping` a phone.  We were trying to set up a "treasure hunt" puzzle.  It did not work as we hoped, because phones go to sleep after a while to save power.

> > [My discontinued phone] seems to have several "modes".  I get 50-100ms [`ping` reponses to start with].  Later, I get
> >     alternately 1000ms and 10ms, and 10% loss.
> >
> > Just tapping the lock button gets it back to the first mode.  Takes
> >     somewhere like 30s to enter the second mode.
>
> You’re a genius! Lock iPhone and 30-60s later it stops responding to pings completely. Press the lock button again to wake it up and it immediately begins responding again.

If it doesn't respond to [multiple ARP probes](https://serverfault.com/questions/205198/arp-tries-on-various-nix-based-systems), I would have said it was completely asleep.  No ARP = no TCP/IP.

And yet.  Here's the puzzle.  Do the devices provide any "push notifications", e.g. immediate notifications of <del>emails</del> chat messages?  That's got to be relying on TCP/IP.

The default settings for the Linux kernel will expire & remove old ARP entries after [ten minutes or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372011/configuring-arp-age-timeout).  After that expiry, the Linux-based router would be unable to forward the push notifications.

To explain these results, the sleeping phone would have to be deliberately ignoring ARP requests unless they are from the router.  That's not impossible, I'm just surprised that it would be considered necessary!  I guess it might be done to cut off some chatty local network discovery protocol that the phone could have been using when active, such as uPNP?

EDIT: I suspect you can't find any code like this when you look in the Android Linux kernel itself.  The specific behaviour may be determined by [ARP offload](https://www.reddit.com/r/nexus4/comments/1dvrl2/possibly_stupid_question_re_the_wifisleeparp_bug/) code in the Wi-Fi device firmware.

To test this behaviour, you would

1. set up a Linux device, to work as a Wireless Access Point and router
2. run a packet sniffer on the Linux device's Wi-Fi interface
3. connect a phone to it
4. wait for the phone to go to sleep & stop responding to probes
5. wait for the ARP entry to expire on the Linux device
6. send the phone an <del>email</del> message using a chat app.

> By default, your Android device turns off the Wi-Fi module during off-peak hours when the device is not being used, and this is a part of the Doze Mode.
>
> -- a third-party non-technical article: https://www.theandroidsoul.com/how-to-fix-delayed-notifications-problem-on-android/

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

> **Normal priority** messages are delivered immediately when the app is in the foreground. When the device is in Doze, delivery may be delayed to conserve battery. For less time-sensitive messages, such as notifications of new email ... choose normal delivery priority.
>
> FCM attempts to deliver **high priority** messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access).

Also, if the phone has no chat apps installed & enabled, only "low priority" notifications like email, then maybe it will only poll periodically, and the rest of the time maybe it does not respond even to ARP.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I will try this tomorrow

Comment: @HeinzR To be honest, it is more of a followup question, I am not sure whether it will answer your own question :-).  I don't know if you have the necessary equipment.  E.g. not all laptops have Wi-Fi that can create an access point.  I think it's possible to buy USB Wi-Fi that can though.

Comment: But I like the idea. Its a complete diffrent way, so i will try i out

Comment: The idea was nice, but i don´t want to get every second a push notification to my smartphone. I want to display a list of known IP adresses in my local network, so i must know if a device is no longer in range.

Comment: @HeinzR you misunderstand. I claim that if the phone did not respond to ARP requests from the router, then it would not be able to receive immediate push notifications.  But, although I do not use smartphones, I hypothesize they can receive push notifications nearly immediately.  I may be wrong!  If all my assumptions are correct, then it is possible for a router to find passive devices by sending ARP probes for every IPv4 address within the subnet.  My own question is - if the router could do this, why don't your ARP scans work?

Comment: @HeinzR One answer might be that the phones treat the router specially. I am just a bit surprised that they would bother, rather than responding to ARP requests from any device.

Comment: If my smartphone is in standby i can receive push notifications from Whatsapp, email...But arp-scan only finds my smartphone if it is on.

Comment: I've edited out your reference to TCP/IP. TCP is a higher level protocol and nothing to do with ARP or mandatory for push notifications. I think you just mean IP

Comment: @PhilipCouling [archaic meaning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).  Unsure how to express the point clearly without that archaism.  "IP" is too short.

Comment: @sourcejedi not that archaic, but misleadingly ambiguous in this context.  Now that I review it, its actually wrong.  ARP is required only for IPv4.  The TCP/IP stack using only IPv6 doesn't use it.  Perhaps replacing your "TCP/IP" references with "IPv4" would be long enough and unambiguous enough?